# How to find address of registers in STM32L4x6

Tags: assembly, stm32ldiscovery

I am using NUCLEO-L476RG board.
I am trying to toggle an LED present in the board. I have to set the register value to 0x01 to enable clock to Port A.

Please help me in finding address of the register "**AHB2 peripheral clock enable register (RCC_AHB2ENR)**" to 0x01.

I am programming in assembly and hence i am finding the address directly.

I have found out the address of GPIO part here:

```
LDR R0, =0x48000000; GPIOA_MODER address
LDR R1, =0xABFFF7FF; GPIOA_MODER value
STR R1, [R0];

LDR R0, =0x48000004; GPIOA_OTYPER address
LDR R1, =0x00000000; GPIOA_OTYPER value
STR R1, [R0];

LDR R0, =0x48000014; GPIOA_ODR address
LDR R1, =0x00000000; GPIOA_ODR value
STR R1, [R0];
```

Please guide me on how to find the address of the registers. thanks!

The product details here:
http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/product-evaluation-tools/mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-eval-tools/stm32-mcu-nucleo/nucleo-l476rg.html

I might be wrong but i have computed address here: can anybody confirm:

```
#define RCC_BASE              (AHB1PERIPH_BASE + 0x1000)
#define AHB1PERIPH_BASE       (PERIPH_BASE + 0x00020000)
#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000) /*!< Peripheral base address */
```

therefore `RCC_BASE = 0x40000000 + 0x00020000 + 0x1000 + 0x4C = 0x4002104c`

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me assuming, that is, you mean -

```
RCC_BASE =    0x40021000
RCC_AHB2ENR = 0x4002104C
```